# Laravel link to route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm grouping `profile` controller and I want to link to that. Then I define this route:

```
//Group to put all the routes that need login first
Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin', 'before' => 'csrf'), function(){
    Route::resource('/profile' , 'ProfileController', array('as'=>'profile') );
});
```

and this is my menu link:

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('admin.profile') }}">profile Managment</a></li>
```

and this it my result of `route` in terminal:

```
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                              | Name                   | Action                    | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET /                            | index                  | Closure                   |                |               |
|        | GET admin/index                  | dashboard              | Closure                   |                |               |
|        | GET logout                       | logout                 | Closure                   |                |               |
|        | POST auth                        | auth                   | Closure                   | csrf           |               |
|        | GET login                        | login                  | Closure                   |                |               |
|        | GET admin/profile                | admin..profile.index   | ProfileController@index   | csrf           |               |
|        | GET admin/profile/create         | admin..profile.create  | ProfileController@create  | csrf           |               |
|        | POST admin/profile               | admin..profile.store   | ProfileController@store   | csrf           |               |
|        | GET admin/profile/{profile}      | admin..profile.show    | ProfileController@show    | csrf           |               |
|        | GET admin/profile/{profile}/edit | admin..profile.edit    | ProfileController@edit    | csrf           |               |
|        | PUT admin/profile/{profile}      | admin..profile.update  | ProfileController@update  | csrf           |               |
|        | PATCH admin/profile/{profile}    |                        | ProfileController@update  | csrf           |               |
|        | DELETE admin/profile/{profile}   | admin..profile.destroy | ProfileController@destroy | csrf           |               |
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Now I get this error:

```
ErrorException

Route [admin.profile] not defined. (View: /var/www/alachiq/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) (View: /var/www/alachiq/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) (View: /var/www/alachiq/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php)
```

Comment: In your route name admin profile is registered as "admin..profile" with the double dot. I think is related to "/profile" try with "profile"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `/` character from your `Route::resource` method. It is causing the double dots, which in turn are causing your error message.

Should be:

`Route::resource('profile' , 'ProfileController', array('as'=>'profile') );`

Either format (`/profile` or `profile`) would usually work, but when using the `prefix` option with `Route::group` you need to remove the `/` from resource URL.

**EDIT:** Also it seems to me that you should be pointing your link to route `admin.profile.index`, not `admin.profile`.

Comment: i get this error now: `Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException`

Comment: That's you're CSRF tokens... not matching... you're route works as per your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do `URL::to('admin/profile');`

Since what you're trying to achieve with `URL::route('admin.profile');` is almost the same number of types away.

Now from what I understand, `URL::route('profile');` will produce a full URL string to a a route with the same name you assigned to.

**EDIT**

```
echo URL::route('admin.profile.index');
```

Should work. Based from [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers), you should include .index under `ROUTE NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution For Laravel 5.6 and above

First step: do `php artisan route:list` in the terminal of your IDE.

Second step: find the admin/profile in the URI column.

Third step: in the Name column related to that uri you should find some thing like 
`profile.index`

Last Step: You should use name provided in third step in your href.

Note: Contrary to laravel 5.3 in laravel 5.6 and above using `admin.profile.index` would not work

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.❤❤❤❤❤